# How to load excel or csv file using java in Jmeter within Webdriver Sampler

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, load

I want  to perform load testing, so need to access atleast 30 user names and password stored in excel or csv file, so how to do this using webdriver sampler in Jmeter.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help
center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). What have you tried? Please post your code that doesn't work, SO isn't a 'write my code for me' service.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can load a CSV file normally using [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG), JMeter will read the CSV file entries into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
2. In the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) you have **WDS.vars** shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance so if you defined `username` and `password` variables in the CSV Data Set Config you should be able to use them as `WDS.vars.get('username')` and `WDS.vars.get(password')` in the WebDriver Sampler correspondingly

   [image]

Comment: This solution is very simple and easy to read the data from CSV file. But how can I write data to CSV with my results with same CSV data set config? Any example would be great. thanks